# Run java program on Heroku using javac

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have a Ruby on Rails app on Heroku that needs to dump some code into a .java file and run `javac file.java` and `java file` inside Heroku terminal. The code runs fine on local since Java is installed, so I want to know how to install Java on Heroku?

Comment: Keep in mind that Heroku has an "epheremal" file system meaning they will intermittently reset the filesystem to the git repo's last commit. You can use the `/tmp` directory to write on Heroku machines anyway but don't consider them persistent files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to add the `heroku/jvm` buildpack to your app by running:

```
$ heroku buildpacks:add -i 1 heroku/jvm
```

Then redeploy, and shell out to `javac`.

However, this is probably not the way you want to accomplish what you're trying to do. I suspect it would be better to run `javac` during the build-phase (when you run `git push`) so that your compiled Java `.class` file is available to you app precompiled.

To do this, you can put your `javac` call in your `assets:precompile` Rake task like this:

```
task "assets:precompile" do
  `javac File.java`
end
```

Then it will run as part of your build.